# Error on publishing Android project

Tags: smartface.io

It shows unable to open file for read: no such file or directory 
(the directory shown in the error message should be linking to the Android SDK folder, the directory shown in the error message is wrong and i tried to rename the folders to make the directory correct but it doesn't work as the directory shown in error message change every time...)

Is there any way to fix it? i have reinstalled it but still doesn't work. Thanks guys

Comment: Can you please provide some code of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the name of the SDK Folders.

I suggest you to install a fresh Android SDK from

http://services.smartface.io/File/Download/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

After that, set the path again from File -> Project Details -> Android SDK tab.